# Yii2 ActiveDataProvider fetch result correct but showing totalCount 0 in summary text

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to filter data using dropdown so the query executed perfectly produces a result is always correct but in summary total count is '0' always but not first time when page loaded. This is annoying me I am completely unable  to trace the error through debugging tool.

But the important thing is that the same code is working fine on my local machine whenever I deployed the same code to production it shows 0 counts

My Model Code :

```
public function search($params) {

    $query = Tasks::find();

    $query->where(['q_id' => $this->job_id]);

    // $query->orderBy('created_at DESC');

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 20,
        ],
    ]);


    $this->load($params);

    if (!empty($this->keyword) || $this->keyword != '') {

        $query->andWhere('MATCH(task_title,task_description, priority) AGAINST("' . $this->keyword . '*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)');
    }

    if (is_numeric($this->filterby)) {
        $query->andFilterWhere(['status' => $this->filterby]);
    } else {
        $query->andFilterWhere(['IN', 'status', [10, 4, 2]]);
    }

    if (!empty($this->sortby) || $this->sortby != '') {
        $query->orderBy($this->sortby . ' DESC');
    }

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

This is my view code :

```
<?php
yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['id' => 'tasks-pjax', 'timeout' => 10000]);
echo \yii\widgets\ListView::widget([
    'layout' => '{summary}<br/>{items}{pager}',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'summary' => '<div class="col-lg-12 hidden-xs"><p class="text-muted text-success"> {totalCount} Tasks Found!</p></div>',
    'summaryOptions' => ['style' => 'margin-bottom: 5px;margin-top:5px;', 'tag' => 'span'],
    'id' => 'tasks-list',
    'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'task-item'],
    'emptyText' => 'No Task Found !',
    'emptyTextOptions' => ['class' => 'list-group-item', 'style' => 'margin-left: 15px; margin-right:15px; color: red'],
    'itemView' => '_tasks',
    'pager' => [
        'class' => 'kop\y2sp\ScrollPager',
        'container' => '#tasks-list',
        'item' => '.task-item',
        // 'next' => '.next a',
        'triggerOffset' => 20,
        'noneLeftText' => '',
    ]
])
?>
<?php yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Controller Code :

```
public function actionIndex() {

    $searchModel = new \frontend\models\TasksSearch();

    if (Yii::$app->request->get('q_id')) {
        $qModel = QPosts::findOne(['q_id' => base64_decode(Yii::$app->request->get('q_id'))]);
        $searchModel->q_id = $qModel->q_id;

        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        if (Yii::$app->user->identity->id == $qModel->user_id || Yii::$app->user->identity->id == $xxxModel->xxx_id) {
            return $this->render('index', [
                        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                        'qModel' => $qModel,
            ]);
        } else {
            return $this->redirect(['xxxx/xxxx', 'id' => $qModel->q_id]);
        }
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

Comment: show also your related controller /action  and view (gridView)

Comment: Added the view code and controller code above

Comment: While you are talking about different results for different two hosts, so you have to regard the versions of both, PHP, MySQL (or the DB used in general) and the OS for each host.

Comment: problem is here $query->where(['q_id' => $this->job_id]); when I comment this code everything is working fine. my get pram is diffrenet for q_id means it is not with model or formName like Model['q_id'] it is q_id

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue.  My activerecord query had a joinWith and I forgot to add a groupBy in the query so it was duplicating rows.  I was using the ListView widget and it was getting the {items} {pager} or {summary} wrong (I forget).  Anyway adding a groupBy on my query with a joinWith solved my issue.

Comment: can you elaborate more on your solution?

Answer (score 0):

can you post your grid code? is there a pjax around? what is in your `$dataProvider->models`?

just a few other things i noticed, without answering your original question:

instead of

```
$query->orderBy($this->sortby . ' DESC');
```

try

```
$query->orderBy([$this->sortby => SORT_DESC]);
```

or what i am doing with states (open/closed/pending/cancelled, active=open or pending, inactive=closed or cancelled):

```
<?php
namespace common\models;
use Yii;

class Status
{
    const UNDEFINED = 0;
    const OPEN      = 1;
    const CLOSED    = 2;
    const CANCELLED = 4;
    const PENDING   = 8;

    const ACTIVE    = 9;
    const INACTIVE  = 6;


    static function asArray() {
        return [
            self::OPEN      => Yii::t('app', 'Open'),
            self::CLOSED    => Yii::t('app', 'Closed'),
            self::CANCELLED => Yii::t('app', 'Cancelled'),
            self::PENDING   => Yii::t('app', 'Pending'),
        ];
    }

    static function asFilter() {
        return [
            self::ACTIVE    => Yii::t('app', 'Active'),
            self::INACTIVE  => Yii::t('app', 'Inactive'),
            self::OPEN      => Yii::t('app', 'Open'),
            self::CLOSED    => Yii::t('app', 'Closed'),
            self::CANCELLED => Yii::t('app', 'Cancelled'),
            self::PENDING   => Yii::t('app', 'Pending'),
        ];
    }

}
```

in function search($params):

```
if (!empty($this->status))
    $query->andWhere('task.status & :status = task.status', [':status' => $this->status]);
```

a custom StatusColumn:

```
<?php
namespace common\grid;

use Yii;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Json;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\web\JsExpression;
use yii\web\View;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use common\models\Status;

class StatusColumn extends \yii\grid\DataColumn {

    public $attribute      = 'status';
    public $headerOptions  = ['class' => 'text-center', 'style' => 'width: 10em'];
    public $contentOptions = ['class' => 'text-center'];
    public $footerOptions  = ['class' => 'text-center'];

    private $sum1 = 0;
    private $sum2 = 0;

    public function renderDataCell($model, $key, $index) {
        $value      = $model->__get($this->attribute);
        $this->sum1 += ($value === null ? 0 : ($value & Status::ACTIVE ? 1 : 0));
        $this->sum2 += ($value === null ? 0 : ($value & Status::INACTIVE ? 1 : 0));
        return parent::renderDataCell($model, $key, $index);
    }

    protected function renderFooterCellContent() {
        $this->footer = sprintf('%d/%d', $this->sum1, $this->sum2);
        return parent::renderFooterCellContent();
    }

    public function init() {
        parent::init();

        if ($this->content === null) {
            $this->content = function($data, $key, $index) {
                $value = $data->__get($this->attribute);

                switch ($value) {
                    case Status::OPEN :
                        return sprintf('<div class="label label-primary">%s</div>', Yii::t('app', 'Open'));
                        break;

                    case Status::CLOSED :
                        return sprintf('<div class="label label-success">%s</div>', Yii::t('app', 'Closed'));
                        break;

                    case Status::CANCELLED :
                        return sprintf('<div class="label label-danger">%s</div>', Yii::t('app', 'Cancelled'));
                        break;

                    case Status::PENDING :
                        return sprintf('<div class="label label-info">%s</div>', Yii::t('app', 'Pending'));
                        break;

                    default:
                        return sprintf('<div class="label label-default">%s</div>', Yii::t('app', 'undefined'));
                        break;
                }

                return $value;
            };
        }

        if ($this->filter === null) {
            $this->filter = Status::asFilter(); 
        }

        if ($this->footer === null) {
            $sum1 = 0;
            $sum2 = 0;
            $this->footer = sprintf('%d/%d', $this->sum1, $this->sum2);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

and use it in grid:

```
    [
        'class' => 'common\grid\StatusColumn',
    ],
```

Comment: I used ListView with autopagescroller. Yes I also used pjax

Comment: problem is here $query->where(['q_id' => $this->job_id]); when I comment this code everything is working fine. my get pram is diffrenet for q_id means it is not with model or formName like Model['q_id'] it is q_id –

Comment: use public function actionIndex($q_id)  for a named get parameter or public function actionIndex($q_id = null) , if it is optional.

Comment: $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams) is probably killing your $searchModel->q_id = $qModel->q_id. so i would suggest merging like $params = ArrayHelper::merge(Yii::$app->request->queryParams. ['q_id' => base64_decode($q_id)])  --- i think you shouldn't have used base64decode in the first place.